# Can I display the global variables of a RTP in the shell?

Tags: vxworks

In VxWorks, I can display global variables in the shell like so:

```
-> my_global
my_global = 0x103c4110: value = 4 = 0x4
```

Is there a way to do the same with a RTP global variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can display global variables in a specific RTP by using the command (cmd) interpreter and attaching to the RTP.
Here is an example with comments in parenthesis.

```
-> cmd                                   (switch to command interpreter)
[vxWorks *]# rtp exec Hello_RTP.vxe &
Launching process 'Hello_RTP.vxe' ...
Process 'Hello_RTP.vxe' (process Id = 0x105e4d50) launched.
Attachment number for process 'Hello_RTP.vxe' is %1.
[vxWorks *]# echo $my_global             (display my_global in the kernel context)
0x4
[vxWorks *]# %1                          (attach to RTP - can also use rtp attach)
[Hello_RTP]# echo $my_global
0x6b7                                    (global variable from RTP context)
[Hello_RTP]# echo $my_global
0x16e1                                   (same global variable..it increments)
[Hello_RTP]# %0                          (detach from RTP. Go to kernel)
[vxWorks *]# echo $my_global             (back to kernel context)
0x4
```

Note that this is only available in VxWorks 6.x  Before the 6 release, there was no RTP in vxWorks.

Comment: If you have not spawned the rtp from the shell, you need to issue the command `rtp symbols add` once you get to the RTP vxWorks shell

Comment: Is there a way to call an RTP's global function?  I am trying `func call &myFunction &` but that doesn't work for me since the RTP was linked as `nonDebug`

Comment: I needed to link the RTP with `-ldebug` and add `-urtpDbgCmdEnable` to the linker macro `LIBS`.